# anonymous namespaces and the one definition rule

Tags: c++, namespaces, one-definition-rule

Am I violating the One Definition Rule with the following program?

```
// foo.hpp
#ifndef FOO_HPP_
#define FOO_HPP_

namespace {
   inline int foo() {
       return 1;
   }
}

inline int bar() {
    return foo();
}
#endif
//EOF
```

and

```
// m1.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"

int m1() {
    return bar();
}

//EOF
```

and

```
// m2.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"

int m2() {
    return bar();
}

//EOF
```

and finally

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int m1();
int m2();

int main(int, const char* [])
{
    int i = m1();
    int j = m2();

    std::cout << (i+j) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// EOF
```

In the above, note that `foo()` is defined in an anonymous namespace, so I expect that each translation unit `m1.cpp` and `m2.cpp` will get its own version, so there is no violation of the ODR.  On the other hand, `bar()` is just a plain old inline function which happens to call 2 different `foo`s.  So it violates the ODR, right?

*Update:*
  Previously I had macros in the definition of `foo` that changed the value it returned and each of `m1` and `m2` defined the macro differently before including `foo.hpp`. (And with that previous example, `g++` would produce a binary that output `(i+j)` with a value other than what you would expect.) **But in fact this program violates the ODR even if the body of `foo()` is identical.**

Comment: I think this clearly illustrate why using anonymous namespaces or static functions in header files brings troubles :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does violate the ODR. See 3.2/5 which is talking about extern inline functions (`bar`):

> in each definition of D, corresponding names, looked up according to
>   3.4, shall refer to an entity defined within the definition of D, or shall refer to the same entity...

In this case `bar` refers to two different versions of `foo`, thus violating the rule.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this definition of `bar()` does violate the One Definition Rule. You are creating multiple definitions, each of which calls a different function called `foo()`.

As you say, it would be a violation even if all versions of `foo()` are identical, since they are still different functions.