# using constants in header file with ODR compliance

Tags: c++, c++11, one-definition-rule

Looking at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955058/anonymous-namespaces-and-the-one-definition-rule) I realized that I can't use objects or functions from an anonymous namespace through a header file since it'll cause ODR violations in class definitions or inline functions. If this is the case, then is it possible to use named `const` or `constexpr` `static` objects in `inline` functions or in classes safely? For example, if `CONSTANT` was inside of `namespace` below it would be unsafe, but is it okay to use a constant with static linkage?

```
// some header file to be included by multiple .cpp files
static const/*expr*/ int CONSTANT = 2;

inline int f() {
  return CONSTANT;
}

class Cls {
  int mem = CONSTANT;
};
```

Comment: At least in C++17 this is no longer an issue. Oddly, a type alias could solve your problems: `using CONSTANT = std::integral_constant<int, 2>;`

Comment: @Barry the "the object is not odr-used" from M.M's quote removed for C++17 I gather?

Comment: N4606 (which is the latest standard draft according to isocpp.org) still has "the object is not odr-used"

Comment: Naw, now you can just do `static constexpr inline CONSTANT = 2;`

Comment: @Barry Can you provide a reference? And did you mean `static constexpr inline int CONSTANT = 2;`

Comment: @M.M http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r0.pdf

Comment: stroustrup was not happy about it iirc

Comment: @RyanHaining according to that document "A function or variable declared with the constexpr specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable", so `inline` would be redundant. Also I don't see where the changes in that document would make the code no longer be an ODR violation.

Comment: @M.M sorry idk why I thought it would at first.. waiting for Barry's response

Comment: @M.M. Don't know the exact details as to which terms you can omit. Can't hurt to add all three. And yeah, missed the `int`

Comment: @RyanHaining N4606 is dated after that document, and some of the text differs between that document and N4606 so we need to be careful

Comment: @Barry `static inline` doesn't make any sense. Just plain `inline`. And then, since it has external linkage, all uses of the name would refer to the same variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is OK. The full paragraph (C++14 [basic.def.odr/6.2]) is:

> in each definition of `D`, corresponding names, looked up according to 3.4, shall refer to an entity defined within the definition of `D`, or shall refer to the same entity, after overload resolution and after matching of partial template specialization, except that a name can refer to a non-volatile
>   const object with internal or no linkage if the object has the same literal type in all definitions of `D`, and the object is initialized with a constant expression, and the object is not *odr-used*, and the object has the same value in all definitions of `D`; and

This usage does match all of the conditions in the "except ... and ... and ..." part:

- The name `CONSTANT` does in fact refer to a non-volatile `const` object with internal linkage
- It has the same literal type in all definitions of `f()`.
- It is initialized with a constant expression `2`.
- It is not *odr-used*.
- It has the same value in all definitions of `f()`.

The point "It is not *odr-used*" is supposed to mean "It is not *odr-used* within `f()`"  -- i.e. it doesn't break `f()` if you happen to *odr-use* `CONSTANT` elsewhere in the program.

Comment: It definitely is supposed to mean "not odr-used within the definition of `D`".