# Difference between constexpr and inline constexpr global variable

Tags: c++, global-variables, c++17, inline, constexpr

C++17 introduce **helper variable template**:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_integral<T>::value;
```

But I see a lot people miss `inline` key word when they define their own traits, Is this equivalent to following or not?

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_integral<T>::value;
```

Comment: constexpr variables are inline implicitly, so there's no need to use constexpr inline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work)  In particular, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896763

Comment: Basically, the variant *with* `inline` is for preventing ODR violations. If none of your code would trigger an ODR violation, it's not needed, but it's safer to add it nonetheless (just in case). More info : [Should `const` and `constexpr` variables in headers be `inline` to prevent ODR violations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794625/should-const-and-constexpr-variables-in-headers-be-inline-to-prevent-odr-v)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker That's actually a better dupe target.

Comment: @Oblivion constexpr variables are **not** inline implicitly, only constexpr static member variables are inline implicitly. see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).